# Bootstrap NavBar Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

**ON BOOTSTRAP 2.3.2**

Dropdown menu wont appear when I click on it despite me referencing it correctly. As per usual in all Bootstrap based Dropdowns I have added a CDN to read from (The Javascript File). Could some please note why this isn't working? Thanks :)

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Title -->
<title>Control Panel</title>

<!-- Meta -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="30 days">
<meta name="distribution" content="web">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Twipply">

<!-- Stylesheet -->
<link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner"><div class="container">
        <a class="brand">MineRush Control Panel</a>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Punishments       <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="nav-header">PUNISHMENTS</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Ban Player</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Kick Player</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Warn Player</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appears ok here... http://www.bootply.com/eciFuBKf7Y

Comment: Not using 3.0 though, on 2.0 if that makes a difference *forgot to note it*

Comment: Check in developer tools, at your console, for errors.

Javascript error may cause other javascripts to stop running.

Comment: Why are you using the 2.3.1 `.css`, and the 3.1.1 `.js`?

Comment: @JacobCohen Not that either, just checked now and with a button on the actual page it wont have a dropdown either. No errors are logged.

Comment: @Skelly Accidentally did that in the post, updated that in my main document.

Answer (score 1):

Made a mistake and forgot to reference in my jQuery Libs. Woops

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```